# sql query possible nested selects

Tags: sql, select, nested

My boss has had a vision today to completely change the design of my almost complete program.
So here's the query I currently use displaying part numbers in the product group with there pareto position (pareto is a league, 1-100 for example, best selling parts).

What my boss wish's for is extra columns used for the pareto history.

here's the current code:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[MyParetoConfirmed]
@pgParam varchar(255)

AS
SELECT
   i.pg,
   dbo.OldParetoAnalysis.Pareto,
   i.keycode,
   i.sales6months,
   a.LostSales6Months,
   dbo.NewParetoAnalysis.Pareto

FROM
OPENQUERY(SACBAUTO, 'SELECT                      
                    dbo.product.Keycode,
                    dbo.iLines.Pg,
                    dbo.product.pg as ppg,
                    SUM(COALESCE(dbo.iLines.Qty, 0)) as sales6months,
                    dbo.iLines.Prefix 
                 FROM 
                    Autopart.dbo.product
                 LEFT OUTER JOIN
                    Autopart.dbo.ilines
                 ON
                    dbo.product.keycode = dbo.ilines.part
                    AND ([datetime] > dateadd(month, -6, getdate()) OR [datetime] is null )
                 WHERE
                    (dbo.iLines.Prefix = ''i'' OR dbo.iLines.Prefix is null)
                 group by 
                    dbo.ilines.pg,
                    dbo.product.keycode,
                    dbo.ilines.prefix,
                    dbo.product.pg
                 order by sales6months desc') i
RIGHT JOIN
dbo.OldParetoAnalysis
on
i.keycode collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS = dbo.OldParetoAnalysis.Part
AND (i.pg = @pgParam or (i.pg is null AND i.ppg  = @pgParam))
INNER JOIN
dbo.NewParetoAnalysis
ON
dbo.OldParetoAnalysis.Part collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS =   dbo.NewParetoAnalysis.Part

LEFT JOIN
OPENQUERY(SACBAUTO, 'SELECT                      
                    dbo.product.Keycode,
                    dbo.aLines.Pg,
                    SUM(COALESCE(dbo.aLines.Qty, 0)) as lostsales6months,
                    dbo.aLines.Prefix 
                 FROM 
                    Autopart.dbo.product
                 LEFT OUTER JOIN
                    Autopart.dbo.alines
                 ON
                    dbo.product.keycode = dbo.alines.part
                    AND ([datetime] > dateadd(month, -6, getdate()) OR [datetime] is null )
                 WHERE
                    (dbo.aLines.Prefix = ''d'' OR dbo.aLines.Prefix is null)
                 group by 
                    dbo.alines.pg,
                    dbo.product.keycode,
                    dbo.alines.prefix
                 order by lostsales6months desc') a
ON
dbo.NewParetoAnalysis.Part collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS = a.keycode
WHERE(i.pg = @pgParam or (i.pg is null AND i.ppg  = @pgParam) AND dbo.NewParetoAnalysis.Pareto is not null)
GROUP BY
   i.pg,
   dbo.OldParetoAnalysis.Pareto,
   i.keycode,
   i.sales6months,
   a.LostSales6Months,
   dbo.NewParetoAnalysis.Pareto
ORDER BY
i.sales6months Desc
```

what I need is a new Table joined called paretoMain, this holds the pareto peroid history:

fields are :  Pg, Part, Pareto, PareoidID, date.

currently there are 20K parts with a unique peroid ID 1- 6,  I need to get the pareto for that peroid and pg like my code already does (just doesnt get the peroid) and I need to do this 6 times for each peroid ID 1-6.
I think it may be multipule select statements or nests but to be honest I cant rap my head around how large the query is going to be and how much is needed.

Help on this would be great!

Many thanks!

To clarify each select will get the pareto from the new table. each select will get pareto and alias as pareto1 , pareto2 .....etc.
So the query needs to select and name 6 times bu still use the query I currently have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok the solution was to change the tables itself into seperate ones. and simply join them through views.